# Una aplicación en Python funciona correctamente co el código en un archivo, pero si paso las funciones a un módulo un IntVar da problemas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Os paso los dos archivos que tengo creados, el segundo en el módulo donde he puesto la función. Si toda es ta información esta en un solo archivo funciona de maravilla, el problema es cuando cambias la función al modulo que el campo `IntVar` que he creado en el archivo principal no puedo asignarle un valor set a través de la función. He probado variables globales, pero no se bien lo que estoy haciendo mal.

El error que da es el siguiente:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'set'.

Éste es mi módulo principal:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from Modulo1.funciones import *

#---------------------Funciones directas ----------------------

solucion=0

def borrar():
    datosString.set("") 
    solucion.set(0)


def salir():

    opcion=messagebox.askquestion("Valorar STRING","Confirma si quieres salir de la aplicación")

    if opcion=="yes":
        root.destroy()



#-----------------Aqui empiezo a construir la ventana de la aplicacion ----------------     

root=Tk()
root.geometry("500x320+500+200")
root.config(bg="#847E7E")
root.resizable(0,0)

BarraMenu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=BarraMenu, width=200,height=25)

Opciones=Menu(BarraMenu, tearoff=0)
Opciones.add_command(label="Calcular", command=valorarString)
Opciones.add_command(label="Limpiar Campos", command=borrar)
Opciones.add_command(label="Salir", command=salir)

BarraMenu.add_cascade(label="Opciones", menu=Opciones)

#------------------------------ Aquí empiezo a construir los contenedores ---------------------------
#global solucion

datosString=StringVar()
solucion=IntVar(value=0)


Contenedor0=Frame(root, padx=5,pady=5,bg="#847E7E")
Contenedor0.pack()

Label0=Label(Contenedor0, text="VALOR del STRING")
Label0.grid(row=0,column=0)
Label0.config(bg="#847E7E",font=("Cooper Black",18),fg="#FFFFFF")

Contenedor1=Frame(root, padx=10,pady=20,bg="#847E7E")
Contenedor1.pack()

Label1=Label(Contenedor1, text=" Escribe el string", width=15,bg="#847E7E")
Label1.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=5, sticky="e")
Label1.config(bg="#847E7E",font=("Arial Roundel Bold",15),fg="#FFFFFF")

Datos1=Entry(Contenedor1,textvariable=datosString, width=30)
Datos1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10,ipady=5, sticky="nsew")
Datos1.config(bg="#FDF6B7",fg="#412AEA" ,font=("Selawik Semibold",12),justify="center")
Datos1.focus_set()

Contenedor2=Frame(root, padx=5,pady=5,bg="#847E7E")
Contenedor2.pack()

BotonCalcular=Button(Contenedor2,text="CALCULAR", width=48, command=lambda:valorarString(datosString.get()))
BotonCalcular.grid(row=0,column=0, pady=5)
BotonCalcular.config(bg="#0EB6C0",font=("Selawik Semibold",12),fg="#FFFFFF", relief=RIDGE, )

Contenedor3=Frame(root, padx=5,pady=5,bg="#847E7E")
Contenedor3.pack()

LabelR=Label(Contenedor3,text="VALORACION: ", width=15)
LabelR.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="e")
LabelR.config(bg="#847E7E",font=("Arial Roundel Bold",15),fg="#FFFFFF")

Resultado=Entry(Contenedor3,textvariable=solucion, width=20)
Resultado.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10, ipady=5, sticky="nsew")
Resultado.config(bg="#D6F7F0", fg="#FF0B0B", font=("Selawik Semibold",18), justify="center")

Contenedor4=Frame(root,bg="#847E7E")
Contenedor4.pack()

BotonLimpiar=Button(Contenedor4,text="Eliminar", command=borrar)
BotonLimpiar.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=10,pady=15, ipadx=5,ipady=1)
BotonLimpiar.config(bg="#EDE8E8",font=("Comic Sans",10),fg="#000000", relief=RAISED)

BotonSalir=Button(Contenedor4,text="SALIR", command=salir)
BotonSalir.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=10,pady=15, ipadx=5,ipady=1)
BotonSalir.config(bg="#EDE8E8",font=("Comic Sans",10),fg="#000000", relief=RAISED)


root.mainloop()
```

y éste `funciones.py`:

```
#------------------------------CALCULOS y Funciones ---------------------------------------

#Creo un diccionario con los valores asignados a cada letra
LetrasValor={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5,
             "f":6,"g":7,"h":8,"i":9,"j":10,
             "k":11,"l":12,"m":13,"n":14,"ñ":15,
             "o":16,"p":17,"q":18,"r":19,"s":20,
             "t":21,"u":22,"v":23,"w":24,"x":25,
             "y":26,"z":27,"ç":3,"Ç":3,
             "á":1,"é":5,"í":9,"ó":16,"ú":22,
             "Á":1,"´É":5,"Í":9,"Ó":16,"Ú":22,
             "â":1,"ê":5,"î":9,"ô":16,"û":22,
             "Â":1,"´Ê":5,"Î":9,"Ô":16,"Û":22,
             "à":1,"è":5,"ì":9,"ò":16,"ù":22,
             "À":1,"´È":5,"Ì":9,"Ò":16,"Ù":22,
             "ä":1,"ë":5,"ï":9,"ö":16,"ü":22,
             "Ä":1,"´Ë":5,"Ï":9,"Ö":16,"Ü":22,
             "0":0,"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,
             "5":5,"6":6,"7":7,"8":8,"9":9,
             "'":0,"-":0,"_":0,"(":0,")":0,"/":0,
             "¿":0,"?":0,"¡":0,"!":0,"º":0,"ª":0,
             "$":0,"%":0,"&":0,";":0,":":0,"*":0,
             "{":0,"}":0,"[":0,"]":0,"#":0,"@":0}
#solucion=0
def valorarString(palabras):
    global solucion
    solucion=0
    total=0
    valor=0
    largo=0

    palabras=palabras.lower()

    print("Despues: ",palabras)

    palabras=palabras.replace(" ","")
    largo=len(palabras)
    print(palabras)
    print("El largo es: ",largo)

    for i in palabras:

        valor=int(LetrasValor[i])
        print("Ahora valor es: ",valor)

        total+=valor
        total=int(total)
        print("Aquí TOTAL vale: ",total)



    solucion.set(total)
```

Comment: el contenido de funciones.py esta ya agragado en la parte final del código que figura, despues de root.mainloop(),. No entiendo que diferencia hay entre un entero y un IntVar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se produce por una serie de circunstancias que en esencia son consideradas malas prácticas, principalmente porque causan cosas como ésta

- En `funciones.py` haces:

  ```
  def valorarString(palabras):
      global solucion
      solucion=0
  ```

  primero usas variables globales, las cuales debes evitar siempre que sea posible. Su uso se debe restringir a variables de estado del módulo y preferiblemente para constantes.

  El segundo error es asignar a `solucion` un entero (literal). `solucion` en el módulo principal es un objeto `tkinter.StringVar` y aquí haces que sea un entero. Un entro es un tipo nativo de Python, instancia de `int`, `tkinter.StringVar` por su parte es una clase de Tkinter que sirve para representar enteros y que añade funcionalidades extra, por ejemplo actualizar automáticamente todo widget que la usa como variable cuando su valor cambia.

  Si haces `solucion = 0`, crea un nuevo objeto `int` y se lo reasignas a `solucion`. Ahora `solucion` hace referencia un objeto `int` y no una `IntVar`, por lo que entre otras cosas no tendrá el método de instancia `set`. Es por esto, que para darle un valor a una `IntVar` se debe usar su método `set`, en vez de:

  ```
  solucion = 0
  ```

  debe ser:

  ```
  solucion.set(0)
  ```
- El segundo problema es usar wildcard (`from modulo import *`) para importar.

  Importar así es una mala práctica en el 99% de los casos. Las razones son varias, primero importas todos los nombres del módulo al espacio de nombres actual. Muchos de esos nombres ni los usas, pero pueblas el namespace principal con ellos...

  Derivado de lo anterior, tiene un enorme peligro al posibilitar el solapamiento inadvertido y no deseado de nombres entre namespaces, especialmente cuando no conoces totalmente el namespace completo de los módulos importados.

  Por último, pero no menos importante, dificultas enormemente la legibilidad del código al no saber con seguridad de que módulo viene cada nombre que usas.  La legibilidad en el mundo Python cuenta mucho, pero en cualquier lenguaje aplicar el [zen de Python](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_de_Python) no es mala idea.

Lo anterior se combina en tu caso para ocasionar un error que, aunque simple de depurar en este caso para alguien que sepa que buscar, en códigos más extensos puede ser una pesadilla.

Al definir tu variable como global en la función `valorarString`, cuando haces `solucion=0` asigna un `int` a la variable global `solucion` cuando la llamas. Como además importas con wildcard, la variable global `solucion` del módulo principal y la del importado se solapan... Como se ha comentado `int` y `tkinter.IntVar` son cosas muy distintas, al intentar llamar al método `set` de `int` tenemos el mencionado error.

Te recomiendo algunas cosas:

- No intentes usar la variable `solucion` desde `funciones.py` como global, puedes pasar la variable  a la función como argumento o mejor, haces que la función retorne un `int` y que dicho módulo no interactué directamente con la app de Tkinter.
- No uses widcard para importar, ahorrarse unos caracteres al escribir no justifica esta mala práctica. Al final pierdes más tiempo depurando u otros leyendo tu código que lo que ahorras al tipear, más con cualquier editor/ide moderno con autocompletado. Además, puedes usar alias o importar aquellos nombres que quieras usar de forma explícita.
- Te recomiendo seguir la [guía de estilo para código Python definidas en PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). No es obligatorio, pero de nuevo, hacen el código más legible y estandarizado para cualquier desarrollador.

Tu código podría quedar así:

**`funciones.py`**

```
# ------------------------------CALCULOS y Funciones --------------------------

# Creo un diccionario con los valores asignados a cada letra
LETRAS_VALOR = {
    "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5,
    "f": 6, "g": 7, "h": 8, "i": 9, "j": 10,
    "k": 11, "l": 12, "m": 13, "n": 14, "ñ": 15,
    "o": 16, "p": 17, "q": 18, "r": 19, "s": 20,
    "t": 21, "u": 22, "v": 23, "w": 24, "x": 25,
    "y": 26, "z": 27, "ç": 3, "Ç": 3,
    "á": 1, "é": 5, "í": 9, "ó": 16, "ú": 22,
    "Á": 1, "´É": 5, "Í": 9, "Ó": 16, "Ú": 22,
    "â": 1, "ê": 5, "î": 9, "ô": 16, "û": 22,
    "Â": 1, "´Ê": 5, "Î": 9, "Ô": 16, "Û": 22,
    "à": 1, "è": 5, "ì": 9, "ò": 16, "ù": 22,
    "À": 1, "´È": 5, "Ì": 9, "Ò": 16, "Ù": 22,
    "ä": 1, "ë": 5, "ï": 9, "ö": 16, "ü": 22,
    "Ä": 1, "´Ë": 5, "Ï": 9, "Ö": 16, "Ü": 22,
    "0": 0, "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4,
    "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, "8": 8, "9": 9,
    "'": 0, "-": 0, "_": 0, "(": 0, ")": 0, "/": 0,
    "¿": 0, "?": 0, "¡": 0, "!": 0, "º": 0, "ª": 0,
    "$": 0, "%": 0, "&": 0, ";": 0, ":": 0, "*": 0,
    "{": 0, "}": 0, "[": 0, "]": 0, "#": 0, "@": 0
    }


def valorar_string(palabras):
    total = 0

    palabras = palabras.lower().replace(" ", "")

    for caracter in palabras:
        valor = LETRAS_VALOR.get(caracter, 0)
        total += valor

    return total
```

**`main.py`**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from funciones import valorar_string


# ---------------------Funciones directas --------------------------------------
def borrar():
    datos_string.set("")
    solucion.set(0)


def salir():
    opcion = messagebox.askquestion(
        "Valorar STRING", "Confirma si quieres salir de la aplicación"
        )
    if opcion == "yes":
        root.destroy()


def resolver():
    sol = valorar_string(datos_string.get())
    solucion.set(sol)


# -----------------Aqui empiezo a construir la ventana de la aplicacion -------
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x320+500+200")
root.config(bg="#847E7E")
root.resizable(0, 0)

barra_menu = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=barra_menu, width=200, height=25)

opciones = tk.Menu(barra_menu, tearoff=0)
opciones.add_command(label="Calcular", command=resolver)
opciones.add_command(label="Limpiar Campos", command=borrar)
opciones.add_command(label="Salir", command=salir)

barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Opciones", menu=opciones)

# ---------------- Aquí empiezo a construir los contenedores ------------------

datos_string = tk.StringVar(root)
solucion = tk.IntVar(root, value=0)

contenedor_0 = tk.Frame(root, padx=5, pady=5, bg="#847E7E")
contenedor_0.pack()
label_0 = tk.Label(contenedor_0, text="VALOR del STRING")
label_0.grid(row=0, column=0)
label_0.config(bg="#847E7E", font=("Cooper Black", 18), fg="#FFFFFF")

contenedor_1 = tk.Frame(root, padx=10, pady=20, bg="#847E7E")
contenedor_1.pack()
label_1 = tk.Label(
    contenedor_1, text=" Escribe el string", width=15, bg="#847E7E"
    )
label_1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, sticky="e")
label_1.config(bg="#847E7E", font=("Arial Roundel Bold", 15), fg="#FFFFFF")

entry_datos = tk.Entry(contenedor_1, textvariable=datos_string, width=30)
entry_datos.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, ipady=5, sticky="nsew")
entry_datos.config(
    bg="#FDF6B7", fg="#412AEA",
    font=("Selawik Semibold", 12), justify="center"
    )
entry_datos.focus_set()

contenedor_2 = tk.Frame(root, padx=5, pady=5, bg="#847E7E")
contenedor_2.pack()

boton_calcular = tk.Button(
    contenedor_2, text="CALCULAR", width=48,
    command=resolver
    )
boton_calcular.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)
boton_calcular.config(
    bg="#0EB6C0", font=("Selawik Semibold", 12), fg="#FFFFFF", relief=tk.RIDGE
    )

contenedor_3 = tk.Frame(root, padx=5, pady=5, bg="#847E7E")
contenedor_3.pack()

label_r = tk.Label(contenedor_3, text="VALORACION: ", width=15)
label_r.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
label_r.config(bg="#847E7E", font=("Arial Roundel Bold", 15), fg="#FFFFFF")

resultado = tk.Entry(contenedor_3, textvariable=solucion, width=20)
resultado.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, ipady=5, sticky="nsew")
resultado.config(
    bg="#D6F7F0", fg="#FF0B0B", font=("Selawik Semibold", 18), justify="center"
    )

contenedor_4 = tk.Frame(root, bg="#847E7E")
contenedor_4.pack()

boton_limpiar = tk.Button(contenedor_4, text="Eliminar", command=borrar)
boton_limpiar.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=15, ipadx=5, ipady=1)
boton_limpiar.config(
    bg="#EDE8E8", font=("Comic Sans", 10), fg="#000000", relief=tk.RAISED
    )

boton_salir = tk.Button(contenedor_4, text="SALIR", command=salir)
boton_salir.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=15, ipadx=5, ipady=1)
boton_salir.config(
    bg="#EDE8E8", font=("Comic Sans", 10), fg="#000000", relief=tk.RAISED
    )


root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]